# Specifying included XSD url in WSDL using jax-ws

Tags: xsd, wsdl, cxf, jax-ws

We are using cxf with jax-ws configuration.
 In the wsdl file, we have included the schema files like below

```
<xsd:include schemaLocation="xsd=xsd/test.xsd" />
```

After deploying and accessing the server & wsdl file, the wsdl file shows the path of the xsd as,

```
<xsd:include schemaLocation="http://servername/services/servicename?xsd=xsd/test.xsd"/>
```

Our problem is, we are using https, not http. Even though we have hit the wsdl with the https url, the wsdl only show the http url. Is there any way where we can give the url to be included in the XSD file instead of the relative path.

Thank you in advance

Regards
Hari

Comment: Possibly [related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35779040/howto-prevent-jboss-from-rewriting-jax-ws-xsd-import-urls-to-https)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it helps.  we have around 20 xsd files and in each xsd files, we have included few other xsd files, so we have to change the path in all the files, so is there any option where we can  change in a common place. thank you.